# Custom Animations with ng-animate $animate

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I need some help on better understanding custom animations in AngularJS 1.3.

**The objective**

- Click on an element
- Animate separate element on the DOM

I have created the following plunkr with no success

http://plnkr.co/edit/zg3BglCY9VfgPJc2pfNg?p=preview

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>

    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>

    <script src="script.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body ng-app="app">
    <ul>
      <li animate-trigger> Click on me to animate </li>
    </ul>

    <div  class="divtoanimate animated">
      Animate Action Baby
    </div>


  </body>

</html>
```

JS

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate'])

app.directive('animateTrigger', ['$animate', function ($animate) {

    return function (scope, elem, attrs) {

        elem.on('click', function (elem) {

            var el = angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName("divtoanimate"));
            console.log("clicked");
            var promise = $animate.addClass(el, "bounceIn");

            promise.then(function () {
                $animate.removeClass(el, "bounceIn");
            });

        });

    }

}]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use $scope.apply for the initial animation and inside your promise to both add and remove the classes. Check out the code below and the attached plunkr, which demonstrates the animation repeating each time the animage-trigger directive is clicked.

[working-plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ue5i87cXWBMVZkCqEimL?p=preview)

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate'])

app.directive('animateTrigger', ['$animate', function ($animate) {

  return function (scope, elem, attrs) {
    elem.on('click', function (elem) {
      scope.$apply(function() {
        var el = angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName("divtoanimate"));
        var promise = $animate.addClass(el, "bounceIn");
        promise.then(function () {
          scope.$apply(function() {
            $animate.removeClass(el, "bounceIn");
          });
        });
      });
    });
  }
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using the jquery event handler, you need to call `scope.$apply(function() {...})` to perform your $animate calls.

Here's plunkr updated with `scope.$apply`:

http://plnkr.co/edit/qOhLWze8pGkO9dGRp1Sg?p=preview

More on `scope.$apply`:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-$scope.$apply()

Comment: That's great - thanks Why does the animation only occur once?

Comment: You need another $apply it looks like: http://plnkr.co/edit/0mnu1NVPABFAGZX9UsV6?p=preview